# para que sirve el operador ... en js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Tengo duda con respecto al operador mencionado, he aquí un ejemplo, qué papel juega?

```
computed: {
        ...mapGetters({
            vuexGetter: "getter",
        }),
    },
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

En este caso `mapGetters` retornará un objeto con las funciones que hacen de [getters en tu store Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html#the-mapgetters-helper). Todo esto gracias al [operador spread (...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Sintaxis_Spread) que va a extraer cada uno de los getters y dejarlos bajo el objeto `computed`.

En tu caso

```
computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
        vuexGetter: "getter",
    }),
}
```

Es equivalente a

```
computed: {
    vuexGetter() {
        return this.$store.getters.getter;
    }
},
```

Usar la sintaxis de spread te permitiría que tus getters convivan con propiedades computadas locales de tu componente.

```
computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
        vuexGetter: "getter",
    }),
    miCustomProp() {
        ...
    }
},
```

Te dejo algo más de [info de spread y rest (y Vue)](https://escuelavue.es/series/javascript-moderno/javascript-spread-rest/)

Comment: Me a quedado claro, gracias por su tiempo estimado