# Spread types may only be created from object types

Tags: angular, typescript

No acabo de entender que estoy haciendo mal. Estoy conectando datos de Firebase (Firestore) con Angular y me surje el siguiente mensaje al intentar ejecutar:
`Spread types may only be created from object types` en la línea de `...e.payload.doc.data()`.

I don't understant what am I doing wrong. I am connecting data from Firebase (Firestore) with Angular and I get the following message when trying to execute:
`Spread types may only be created from object types` in line `...e.payload.doc.data()`.

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.mealService.getMeals().subscribe(data => {
      this.meals = data.map(e => {
        return {
          id: e.payload.doc.id,
          ...e.payload.doc.data()
        } as Meal;
      })
    });
  }
```

Comment: Quizá te sirva mirar esta pregunta/respuesta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/377415/para-que-sirve-el-operador-en-js/377418#377418

Answer (score 1):

Tal vez podrías intentar algo así:

```js
const data = typeof e.payload.doc.data() === 'object'? e.payload.doc.data() : {}
return {
    id: e.payload.doc.id,
    data
} as Meal;
```

Para asegurarte que lo que le envías al `spread operator` es un `objeto` o tal vez también intentar:

```
let data = e.payload.doc.data() as Partial<Meal>;
return {
    id: e.payload.doc.id,
    data
} as Meal;
```

Aquí hay mas respuestas que podrían ayudarte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51095505/how-to-get-the-payload-and-document-id-from-snapshotchanges-in-angular-6

O esta explicación: https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/typescript-spread-types-may-only-be-created-from-object-types

Comment: No me a acabado de funcionar. Finalmente he añadido la propiedad id al objeto.Sé que no es muy bonito pero por ahora funciona.

También he estado investigando y parece que puede tener algo que ver con la versión de TypeScript. Es posible que con la 3.8.3 funcione, pero no lo he podido probar ya que en esa versión no hay ciertas funcionalidades que necesito.

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente he hecho esto:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.mealService.getMeals().subscribe((data) => {
      this.meals = data.map(e => {
        const data = e.payload.doc.data() as Meal;
        data.id = e.payload.doc.id;
        return { ...data };
      })
    });
  }
```

Sé que no es muy bonito pero por ahora funciona. También he estado investigando y parece que puede tener algo que ver con la versión de TypeScript. Es posible que con la 3.8.3 funcione pero, no lo he podido probar ya que en esa versión no hay ciertas funcionalidades que necesito.

Comment: podes consultar en este link https://wanago.io/2022/01/24/index-signatures-typescript/